# How can I do an absolute div (with some content inside) stretched to its parent div?

Tags: css

Let's say I have positioned a div to be absolute in order to move it using left and top, but I want its content to stretch to its parent container div which has specific height and width (i.e. a width of 300px and a height of 200px).

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you need to do:

1. Give the parent a **[`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)** of anything other than `static` (the default)
2. Give the parent a **[`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)** and **[`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height)**

Then simply give the absolutely-positioned child a relative `width` and `height`.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="absolute"></div>
</div>
```

If you want to make use of both an offset **and** stop the child element from expanding outside the parent container, your best bet is to make use of **[`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)** to subtract the `left` offset from the `width`, and the `top` offset from the `height`:

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="absolute"></div>
</div>
```